# Why cant I use _GET function on Tsohost?

Tags: php, email, get

I'm a relative PHP noob but I'm working through a tutorial and recently had to host it online to use some email functionality. I created an account on Tsohost forums but still don't have the privileges to post, so I'm hoping the good people here will give me some suggestions. Previously I had it running on localhost no problem, but using the code below I'm unable to change the URL :p

```
register_user($register_data);
header('Location: register.php?success');
```

I know I could achieve the same thing by reworking it to use _POST but I really want to move on with the tutorial. Is it a host setting?

I think both versions of PHP are the latest. Thanks!

Comment: hard to answer this to  many questions, post them separately. last one, check with your host they should have a page on what settings you will give to the name register (probably 2 DNS IP's)

Comment: thanks, well that answers my question really. Your suggesting I use the custom DNS option. Thats the last thing I did, so it would make sense if thats whats pointing the DNS. There was lots on info on each method but I wasnt sure which would suit my needs. So now it just the _get function I cant fathom.

Comment: yup last one. your web host should provide 2+ DNS names\IP's

Comment: Thanks Dagon, that seems to be working now so ive removed the second part of the question.

Comment: maybe there is a simple syntax error when accessing the variable from $_GET. Can you post the snippet where you do that?

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question - please edit with the problematic code if you are still having problems with this.